# jasypt property placeholder not working

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have this properties file:

```
secret.key = ENC(foobar)
region = ABC
```

Then in the `config.xml`:

```
<spring:beans>

    <encryption:encryptor-config id="eConf" password-sys-property-name="MULE_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" algorithm="PBEWithMD5AndDES" password="" />
    <encryption:string-encryptor id="stringEnc" config-bean="eConf" />
    <encryption:encryptable-property-placeholder encryptor="stringEnc" location="${env}.properties" />

</spring:beans>
```

But the property placeholders don't work, for example:

```
<sqs:config secretKey="${secret.key}" region="${region}"></sqs-config>
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encrypted password needs to be write within ENC() function and should be encrypted.

Let's consider in properties file where password value is Login@123... Now the encrypted value in properties file will be :-

```
password=ENC(B0u7D8wLwq/ugin31KNpP78gBcLP7VIN)
```

**Step1** :- We can generate Key using following commands in Command prompt of \jasypt-1.9.2\bin directory :- `encrypt input="Login@123" password=sqlpassword algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES`

**Step2** :- In runtime Environment we need to give (Right click->Run As->Run Configuration->Environment) :- Variable :- MULE_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD and Value:-sqlpassword

In your **Mule config**, you need configure it as following :-

```
 <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
            <spring:property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES"/>
            <spring:property name="passwordEnvName" value="MULE_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD"/>
        </spring:bean>

        <!-- The will be the encryptor used for decrypting configuration values. -->
        <spring:bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
            <spring:property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration"/>
        </spring:bean>

        <!-- The EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer will read the -->
        <!-- .properties files and make their values accessible as ${var} -->
        <!-- Our "configurationEncryptor" bean (which implements -->
        <!-- org.jasypt.encryption.StringEncryptor) is set as a constructor arg. -->

        <spring:bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <spring:constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor"/>
            <spring:property name="locations">
                <spring:list>
                    <spring:value>conf/yourPropertyFile.properties</spring:value>
                </spring:list>
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>
```

Then you can use encrypted values like :- `${password}`

Reference :- http://blogs.mulesoft.org/encrypting-passwords-in-mule/
and http://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/using-encrypted-passwords-with-mule-esb/
and https://code.google.com/p/soi-toolkit/issues/detail?id=183
and http://soi-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2022/wiki/UG_PropertyFile.wiki

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer :) I did put in an encrypted string. Turns out that Anypoint Studio doesn't support reading the placeholder if I use Jasypt (don't know why).

Comment: Yeah, I did. From my understanding, it is essentially the same as what I'm doing with `<encryption:*>` . I tried your approach anyway and didn't work.

Comment: btw, it worked if I build the project and run it instead of trying `Test connection..`

Comment: Great if it worked .. I have given you the detailed steps .. you can also refer the links given there

Comment: I had similar issue, i did configure everything as [Activemq](http://activemq.apache.org/encrypted-passwords.html) . In my case issue was [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) bean was loaded before the EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean. So remove PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean's if any just add EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, i did configure everything as explained in [Activemq web site](http://activemq.apache.org/encrypted-passwords.html) . In my case issue was [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) bean was loaded for to load other properties before the [EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/spring/properties/EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) bean. So remove [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) bean's if any just add [EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/spring/properties/EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) bean even for other non-encrypted properties as explained in [Activemq](http://activemq.apache.org/encrypted-passwords.html) then it works fine.